# Runtime error with Generics

Tags: c#

Is it possible to encounter Runtime error while using Generics? Could anybody give an 
example?

```
  public Someclass<T>
  {

     int i;
   }
```

In what situation, this implementation can encounter an runtime error?  Could anybody show any implementation by which the above class can encounter a runtime error?

Comment: What is your runtime error?

Comment: WHAT? that code will never throw any error, because that code does nothing.

Comment: No, it encounters compile error first

Comment: What are you trying to determine here?

Comment: If all you want to know is if it can be done, just use `throw` and cause your own.

Comment: I think what the OP was asking (albeit in a really unclear way) was: Are C# generics something that are typically resolved at compile time? Or are they dynamic in nature, such that using generics could generate "type errors" at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation you showed doesn't really do anything, so it, itself, is very unlikely to exhibit any runtime errors (other than a potential [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) on creation if you're out of memory).

If you had other code within the class, it, of course, could exhibit different behavior, and cause other errors to occur.  Using this class, as well, could exhibit errors at runtime, but that error would technically be in the code that *used* the class, not arising from within the class itself, as this class has no methods defining behavior.

Comment: +1 It's always a relief to read your sane answers.

Comment: I want to know what implentation can cause runtime error.

Comment: @user1672097 Any implementation that causes an error - it really doesn't matter that the class is a generic class or a regular class.  Any class can create exceptions...